# mongo-connector to a remote mongo public IP with private IP

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect from a server (say `beta.server`, where mongo-connector and elasticsearch exists) to a public IP (say `public.ip.1`, where mongo server exists). The `public.ip.1` has a private ip say `private.ip.p` having port 27017 on which mongo PRIMARY is running. There is another private ip `private.ip.s` on which SECONDARY is running with public IP `public.ip.2` on port 27018. And there is another private ip `private.ip.a` on which ARBITER is running with the same public ip `public.ip.2` on port 27019. The mongo server admin are password secured.

While trying to connect from `beta.server`, using

```
mongo-connector -m mongodb://public.ip.1:27017 -a user -p pass
```

it displays this error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: private.ip.p:27017: timed out,private.ip.s:27018: timed out, private.ip.a:27019: timed out
```

However, I made sure that the ports 27017, 27018 and 27019 of `public.ip.1` and `public.ip.2` have their accessed allowed from `beta.server`.

And even connecting from the `beta.server`

```
 mongo mongodb://public.ip.1:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u user -p pass
```

it gets connected. Even telnet is getting connected on the same ports.

So, Why is the mongo-connector connecting to the private IPs, which is not neeeded and How to resolve it?

Comment: Is that the exact `mongo-connector` command line you are using, or are you also including the `replicaSet` parameter for your MongoDB connection string? If you include the `replicaSet` parameter it is expected that the driver will use the hostnames & ports specified in your replica set configuration. Without this parameter the driver should connect directly to the specified host without doing any replica set discovery or failover.

Comment: No I am not using replicaSet, it gets over all the shards which communicate internally  via their private ips, thus mongo-connector tries to access their private ips.

Comment: Your description appears to be a replica set - do you actually have a sharded deployment or are you referring to replica set members as shards? Is your `mongo-connector` command line exactly as in the current description (` -m mongodb://public.ip.1:27017 `) ? If so, can you confirm the version of PyMongo you are using with `mongo-connector`? A direct/standalone connection with a single hostname should work with the public IP (as per your `mongo` example). A replica set connection will connect using the hostnames and ports in your `rs.conf()`.

Comment: I am not using replicaSet parameter in the command here. Yeah, ofcourse I am running primary, secondary and arbiter replica set members over 2 different public ips in the same LAN, on the replicaSet. Their config in rs.conf() has host with their private IPs. Yeah, mongo connector command is the same.  The PyMongo version is 3.7.2.